# Asp css bundling and minification not woring

Tags: asp.net, optimization

I have setup my css bundling and minification as follows:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles").Include(
  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
  "~/Content/jBox.css"
));
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

and `aspx` page:

```
<%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/styles") %>
```

My debug is set to true.

So the above `css` files are never minified and bundled all i get on the client is a response of the actual `aspx` page.(From the console:

`http://localhost:25509/styles?v=u2-34wMvMx9Wilp6mlMRpN4LuNH9u4ss_wvYmapLmQ1`)

I cannot figure out with it is not working.

The funny thing is that the `.js` is being bundle correctly and minified

Any ideas?

Comment: Does a `<link />` element get generated, or do you just see the URL?

Comment: <link href="/styles?v=u2-l34wMvMx9Wilp6mlMRpN4LuNH9u4ss_wvYmapLmQ1" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: this is what i see in page source

Comment: Does that URL return a 404 response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got it to work, don't really understand why it is working. So my `css` is in a Content folder, I thought virtual directory can be anything thus i used the styles virtual directory. However, once i used `~/Content/css` as virtual directory it worked